# Computer connections without internet

Tags: networking, connection, connection-sharing

I would like to ask a question as I have a problem.

I would like to connect two computers. I would like that computer 2 would access computer 1 hard drive without outside internet connection. How do I do that? Do you have any idea? Because I don't even know if that is even possible.

For all your ideas and suggestions I thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I share files on my home network?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1132/how-do-i-share-files-on-my-home-network)

Answer (score 1):

I need to assume a bit - as your initial post is missing some informations.

**Assuming:**

- both computers are in the same network
- both computers are connected to this local network (be it wired or using wifi) or directly to each other
- computer1 is running linux

**To break it down**

If both computers are in the same local network, it is possible in general.
They both need access to either the same local router or directly to each other.

In case of direct connection:
Connect the computers using a crossover cable (may not be necessary most modern ethernet cards should auto negotiate the connection)

Then configure the network card on both sides accordingly (i would go for fix ip addresses)

To share the files from computer1 to computer2, you would need to setup some kind of network-share on computer1 (There are several options and protocols here - i.e. ssh ,ftp, samba etc). People often use [samba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29) in such cases.

You should be able to find tons of tutorials on how to setup samba, one possible is [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20%28Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal%29%20-%20Uncomplicated,%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way!)

**Even shorter**

Yes it is possible.

Comment: I my case the computer 1 and computer 2 must be connected only with eachother. Nor computer 1 and nor computer 2 can NOT have connection with outside world wide web (internet)... Both computer running Ubuntu.

Comment: @Agent47 but are both computers physically near each other?

Comment: @Zacharee Yes. I was thinking about the connection via USB cable. Is this possible?

Comment: USB? No, not by itself. You need to use Ethernet or WiFi.

Comment: This is a problem. Computers must be isolated from external networks, because I will store confidental data.

Comment: Ethernet or WiFi!= internet

Comment: @Agent47: there is a difference between hosts being connected in a LOCAL network vs the external net (internet)

Answer (score 1):

One alternative could be to set up an SSH server and restrict the access to only your local network. See here for examples: [How can I setup SSH so that it is restricted to my local network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115940/how-can-i-setup-ssh-so-that-it-is-restricted-to-my-local-network). I'm not on linux right now, so I can't double check the name of the package, but you'll probably want `openssh-server`, so try to do `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`. There is loads of guides on the Internet, if you run into problems.

You could then connect to the other computer rather seamlessly with the help of the built in file explorer nautilus. Just do Files -> Connect and then e.g.

```
sftp://user@address/folder/
```